# PlayOnLinux's full-screen mode

Tags: 22.04

How to fit the game into the screen (in full-screen mode) ?

The game does not stretch to full screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The circle of the sight in the call of duty is oval, the aspect ratio is not maintained correctly in this mode.

I could use these scripted games in windowed mode, but I will lose fps if the games in windowed mode is stretched to full screen.

Comment: @david Software being used on Ubuntu is on topic here, whether it's part of the OS or not. playOnLinux is even part of the official repos. It's also fine if screenshots are not in English as long as post contains the necessary information in English.

Comment: @Dan which was not the case till the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found some values that fit me.

```
# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 239mm x 134mm
   1920x1080     59.99 +  59.97    59.96    59.93    47.99  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82* 
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

For example, such as... `1360x768` and `800x450`.
What made it possible to do this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRptx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x6y4.png)

Many values completely disable the device, others just don't work, so I tested selectively.